# Lost Connection to MySQL Server during Query - How to Investigate Network Issue

Tags: mysql

I have read the documentation, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-lost-connection.html

and it mention that it could be a network connectivity issue. I have also tried, configuring the parameters mentioned in the docs, but still experiencing the issue.

The client is a windows machine, and I tried running Test-Connection [mysqlserverip] -port 3306 and the result seems normal.

How do i investigate the potential network issue between the client and server?